# If modality across some domain was such that anything is possible, then does modal logic entail that everything actual is necessary?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

If modality across some domain was such that anything is possible, then does modal logic entail that everything actual is necessary? It seems intuitive that would be the case.

Comment: If it seems intuitive to you why not spell out how? On the face of it if everything is possible then it appears to follow that what is actual is only possible, and not necessary.

Comment: well, i've been confusing myself about necessary possibility [i thought maybe it meant actual] but this is another sort of necessary possibility, it seems.

not A→□◊A but something else??

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. Consider the space of propositions Prop = {p, q}. These propositions are the things that are possible/necessary/actual. Consider the model M = (W, R, V, @) with possible world space W = {w<sub>1</sub>, w<sub>2</sub>}, a distinguished world @ = w<sub>1</sub>, an accessibility relation R = ∅, and a valuation V(q) = {w<sub>1</sub>} and V(p) = {w<sub>2</sub>}.  Intuitively, we have there two worlds w<sub>1</sub> (which is the actual world) and w<sub>2</sub>. We have p true at w<sub>2</sub> and q true at w<sub>1</sub>. The R is such that no world sees anything. For this model we have the following fact:

> **Fact 1.** For any proposition φ ∈ Prop, there exists a world w ∈ |M| s.t. M, w |= φ.

*Proof.* Let φ be an arbitrary proposition in Prop = {p, q}. If φ = p, since V(p) = {w<sub>2</sub>}, we have M, w<sub>2</sub> |= p. If φ = q, since V(q) = {w<sub>1</sub>}, we have M, w<sub>1</sub> |= q.  Since φ was arbitrary, we have established the fact.

The conclusion that you want to draw, however, does not hold for M:

> **Claim 2.** For any proposition φ ∈ Prop, if φ is actual, then φ is necessary.

*Disproof.* Let φ = q. Consider the model M described above. In M, φ is actual at w<sub>1</sub>, since V(φ) = V(q) = {w<sub>1</sub>} = {@}. But is φ necessary in M, that is, is it true that for any world w ∈ |M|, we have M, w |= φ? Since w<sub>2</sub> ∉ V(q) = V(φ), we have M, w<sub>2</sub> |/= φ. Therefore φ is not necessary, so Claim 2 is false.

Therefore, (Fact 1) doesn't entail (Claim 1).

Comment: @user3293056 The recognition that what you're asking isn't very clear is a great first step. Focus on the basics. Define the terms carefully; doesn't have to be the standard definition or the popular one. So long as _you_ understand the terms and distinctions somehow, we'll try to clarify them to a point where everyone can understand and contribute. Some places to begin would be to get clear on the various types of modalities, including the probabilistic ones you had asked about earlier. Then we'll be able to proceed with claims about iterated modalities and their possible implications.

Comment: To say that **p is logically possible** is to say that there is an interpretation of the logical constants that makes p true. If p is (q & ~q), for example, then you can see that there is no interpretation of '&' and '~' that will make p true. Similarly for logical necessity: **p is logically necessary** iff any interpretation of the logical constants makes p true. These can be defined also using possible worlds: **p is logically possible** iff there is a possible S5-world where p is true, and **p is logically necessary** iff p is true in all S5-worlds.

Comment: Now, if we continue talking about _logical_ modalities, then: to say that **p is (logically) necessarily (logically) possible** is simply to say that **p is logically possible**, because p's logical possibility is _not_ dependent on the world of evaluation, i.e., is an absolute and not a relative notion. Similarly for any other iterations of logical modalities.

Comment: It is logically possible that my name is not 'Hunan Rostomyan', and it is (logically) necessary that it is (logically) possible that my name is not that. But it is, nevertheless false in the actual world that my name is not 'Hunan Rostomyan'. So what is logically possible may certainly not be actual. This should seem intuitive.

Comment: @user3293056 What is physically possible is metaphysically possible. What is metaphysically possible is metaphysically _necessarily_ possible, for the reasoning I gave above. Therefore, what is physically possible is metaphysically necessarily possible. Nothing about the actual world follows from these considerations; so far as metaphysical modalities are concerned, there is no actual world. But, of course, what is necessary is actual.

Comment: "(B) says that if A is the case, then A is necessarily possible. One might argue that (B) should always be adopted in any modal logic, for surely if A is the case, then it is necessary that A is possible. However, there is a problem with this claim that can be exposed by noting that ◊□A→A is provable from (B). So ◊□A→A should be acceptable if (B) is." SEP

but i see my mistake anyway, i think.

Comment: @user3293056 (B) and ◊□A→A are exactly the same formula: take its contrapositive to obtain ~A→~◊□A, push the negation in to obtain: ~A→□◊~A, and substitute A for ~A to obtain: A→□◊A, which is just (B). In S5 models both will be valid, since if A is possibly necessary at w then there is a world w' s.t. wRw' and every world w' sees satisfies A. But since in S5 accessibility is symmetrical, w' sees also w, so w too satisfies A.